# Encountering Album Crash Issue on iOS WebKit when Selecting 10MB Image with v-file-input

Tags: ios, webkit

Test iOS version and device
iPhone XR(iOS16.3.1),
iPhone 7(iOS15.6.1)

When I open the album on webkit and select a large image, the album screen closes similar to the crash.

However, Xcode does not cause an error. Is this a cell phone performance problem??

In what way can I solve it??

There is no part of the code that is processed by swift.

There is no other log or response on the web because the album screen closes at the same time as the image is selected.